# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Date in text format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have an issue with a file import. I am trying to import an .xls file into SQL Server. But the issue it is the date format. 
After some debugging, I have found out that I am reading the date in text format. 
My date is f.eg.: '01-01-2017', but when I debug I can not see the date, i can see '42736' instead, which is the text format for the date.
Can anyone help with some ideas about how to solve this?

[image]

```
string strDate = table.Rows[i][2].ToString();
  DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate.Replace(".", "-"));


ImportToAP(Int32.Parse((table.Rows[i][26]).ToString()), date, Double.Parse((table.Rows[i][38]).ToString()), (table.Rows[i][33]).ToString(), Int32.Parse((table.Rows[1][4]).ToString()));
```

Comment: what is the code what you have used for converting excel to table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(table.Rows[i].Field<double>(2));
```

If that's really a string column(what i doubt):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(table.Rows[i].Field<string>(2)));
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. It is a string column and your code helps, but it only imports the last line from the document into the database.

Comment: @Michelle: really a string or only because you have used `ToString`? However, the next problem is not related to this. So you might want to ask another question and insert all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.FromOADate()` method.

Just check if `strDate` can be parsed to double using `Double.TryParse()` method. If so use `DateTime.FromOADate((double)strdate)` else use the default method.

*Reference:*

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx